# Ballerina Test Mock

Tags: testing, mocking, ballerina

I recently started studying Ballerina
can not mock graphql:Client.
repo and pr: https://github.com/zero-hack-org/module-zerohack-github/pull/1

```ballerina
@test:Config {
    dataProvider: testExecuteDataProvider
}
function testExecute(string query) returns error? {
    GraphQlClient|error graphqlClient = new;

    if graphqlClient is error {
        test:assertFail("Unexpected: GraphQlClient is error");
    }
    
    final graphql:Client mockedClient = test:mock(graphql:Client);
    record {|anydata...;|} res = {"username": "test"};
    test:prepare(mockedClient).when("execute").thenReturn(res);
    
    graphql:GenericResponseWithErrors|record {|anydata...;|}|json|graphql:ClientError result = check graphqlClient.execute(query = query);
    if result is graphql:GenericResponseWithErrors {
        test:assertFail("Unexpected: executed response is graphql:GenericResponseWithErrors");
    }
    if result is json {
        test:assertFail("Unexpected: executed response is json");
    }
    if result is graphql:ClientError {
        test:assertFail("Unexpected: executed response is graphql:ClientError");
    }

}
```

error:

> [HttpError due to mock not working]
> error {ballerina/test:0}ExecutionError ("error {ballerina/graphql:1}HttpError&{ballerina/graphql:1}RequestError&{ballerina/graphql:1}ClientError ("GraphQL Client Error",body={"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/graphql"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given test function, it's hard to understand your requirement.
I'm assuming you are trying to mock the external client `githubClient` being used within the `GraphQlClient` you have defined. https://github.com/zero-hack-org/module-zerohack-github/blob/main/graphql.bal#L11
If so, there are few approaches you can take. Please refer to below guides on testing.

https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/test-services-and-clients/
https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/mocking/

Comment: thanks!!
Then I would like to change the implementation to be testable code.